# How to convert datetime from GMT format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Tags: java, datetime-format

How can I convert the following datetime format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

```
Tue, 11 Oct 2022 15:59:46 GMT
```

I already tried this but it doesn't work, it brings the wrong time

```
Date d = new Date("Tue, 11 Oct 2022 15:59:46 GMT");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String f = sdf1.format(d);
System.out.println(f);
```

It's bringing the wrong time when you print:

```
2022-10-11 12:59:46
```

Comment: Stop using outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date` use more modern `java.time`API

Comment: ok, i'll take a look at that package. But can you demonstrate the use of this package?

Comment: Google will show you so much tutorials

Comment: Its converting time zones. It looks like you are working in a GMT-5 timezone. Maybe east coast?

Comment: I was browsing on google, I found the solution!! `sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: @megaultron Much easier to use *java.time*. Avoid the legacy date-time classes like the plague .

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the `setTimeZone` zone in the `SimpleDateFormat`. So I can do the conversion later with `format`.

```
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

full code

```
Date d = new Date("Tue, 11 Oct 2022 15:59:46 GMT");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String f = sdf1.format(d);
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse( 
    "Tue, 11 Oct 2022 15:59:46 GMT" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
)
.format (
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
)
.remove( "T" , " " )
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### Parsing text

Your text is in the format defined by an obsolete standard, RFC 1123 / RFC 822.

The `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` class carries a constant pre-defining a formatter for that: [`RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ) ;
```

### Generating text

The format you desire is close to that of a format defined in the modern standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

The DateTimeFormatter class also carries a predefined formatter for the ISO 8601 standard: [ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

Just remove the `T` to get your desired format.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).remove( "T" , " " ) ;
```